# Tag management in database

Tags: database-design, tags

I am trying to design a database where I will keep track of different objects related to a publication house. The obvious one is keeping track of all the articles. I would like to add one or more "Tag"s to them. But I am not sure how to handle them.

As a first thought I am thinking of a mapping table consists of Tags and corresponding Sub-tags. And another mapping table of mapping of article to those tad-combination id.

Would it be the best way to manage them and use for searching? How does this stackoverflow tagging a question work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic many-to-many situation that you solve with link tables.

If tags and sub-tags are equivalent, then you have two core tables, `Articles` and `Tags`, and one link table `ArticleTags`. If you have a pressing need to differentiate sub-tags, then you have three core tables and two link tables, `Articles`, `Tags`, and `SubTags` linked by `ArticleTags` and `TagSubTags`.

The single level of tag is easier to manage and will be more performant, although whether or not it actually matters will depend on a variety of factors. If sub-tags are named very similarly then a `like` search will still retrieve them, if all tags are in a single table.

To search for a articles by tag you would probably use SQL like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Articles a JOIN ArticleTags at ON a.Id = at.ArticleId JOIN
Tags t ON at.TagId = t.Id WHERE t.TagName Like '%your search criteria%'
```

If you are constructing SQL like this in any public environment be ***VERY*** careful to ensure you bind your parameters correctly to avoid SQL Injection Attacks [link1](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

If you have distinct sub-tags then your SQL will need to be something like this

```
SELECT a.* FROM Articles a JOIN ArticleTags at ON a.Id = at.ArticleId 
JOIN Tags t ON at.TagId = t.Id JOIN TagSubTags tst ON t.Id= tst.TagId
JOIN SubTags st ON tst.SubTagId = st.Id
WHERE t.TagName Like '%your search criteria%'
OR st.SubTagName Like '%your search criteria%'
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using PostgreSQL as database you can make use of the Array type to store multiple values in one column. I covered this in one of my talks, see the slides here: https://talks.bitexpert.de/phpuk15-postgres-nosql/#/12